# NDK Debugging - breakpoints don't hit in Android Studio

Tags: c++, android-ndk, gdb, gdbserver

I'm trying to debug native c/c++ with android studio that execute the gdb debugger, but the breakpoints don't hit.
The gdb displays me this message:

```
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
```

once I execute the "file" command :

```
(gdb) file
A program is being debugged already.
Are you sure you want to change the file? (y or n) [answered Y; input not from terminal]
No executable file now.
No symbol file now.
```

I have already tried to add -g flag to CFlags in build.gradle file but it's does not solve the problem.

I'm using:

- Android Studio 1.3.2 stable
- Gradle 2.5 with experimental plugin 0.2.0

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by updating the android studio to 1.4 beta 2 and by changing the debugger from gdb to lldb.

Comment: Hello. Could you indicate how you managed to change the debugger ? Thank you !